# PHP Translating a ENUM in switch case not working

Tags: php, enums, switch-statement

```
        echo $state;  //debug
        switch($state){
            case "Sleeping":
                $label = "Is Sleeping";
            case "Running":
                $label = "Is Running";
            default: 
                $label = "Could not retrieve state";
        }
```

$state is filled from an SQL database (Enum type), the echo message prints "Sleeping", but the $label is filled with the default value

Comment: You need to include break sentences in each case. The execution is "falling" from the first case until the default. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php You've got a detailed explanation of what is happening in your code in the link.

Comment: right, rookie mistake. I normally know this.. :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP switch statements continue executing the remainder of the switch block after finding a match, until it finds a `break;` statement. You'll want to add `break;` to the end of each case:

```php
        echo $state;  //debug
        switch($state){
            case "Sleeping":
                $label = "Is Sleeping";
                break;
            case "Running":
                $label = "Is Running";
                break;
            default: 
                $label = "Could not retrieve state";
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

In your case choose [`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) (*PHP 8*) expression is significantly shorter and it doesn't require a `break` statement.

```php
$state = "Running";
$label = match ($state) {
    "Sleeping"=> "Is Sleeping",
    "Running" => "Is Running",
    default => "Could not retrieve state"
};
echo $label; // "Is Running"
```

Comment: With a side note that this is a PHP 8 feature.

Comment: Yes, I added a reference to it!

Comment: Is there a way to run two commands on a successful match?

Answer (score 4):

For completeness:

```
$states = [
    'Sleeping' => 'Is Sleeping',
    'Running' => 'Is Running',
];
echo $states[$state] ?? 'Could not retrieve state';
```